# Add multiple conditions in XSLT for a child element

Tags: xml, xslt, xls

I need to format this XML to XSLT. My example doesn`t work for second  condition. My task is show picture when I have multiple condition("$isMissingImg = 'false' and $brand = 'White T-shirt'")

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
  <book>
      <a>
      <ItemFields>
        <ItemMainCategory>White T-shirt</ItemMainCategory>
      </ItemFields>
    </a>
  </book>
</books>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
 <xsl:variable name="isMissingImg">
        <xsl:call-template name="isMissingImage">
          <xsl:with-param name="imgUrl" select="$imgSrc"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <div class="logo">
        <xsl:variable name="brand" select="books/book/a/ItemFields/ItemMainCategory"/>
        <xsl:if test="$isMissingImg = 'false'">
            <h2>Hello</h2> <!-- this condition is working--> 
            <xsl:if test="$brand = 'White T-shirt'"> <!-- this condition is NOT working--> 
          <xsl:element name="img"> 
        <xsl:attribute name="src">  
        <xsl:text>https://example.com/images/black.png</xsl:text> 
        </xsl:attribute> 
        <xsl:attribute name='border'>0</xsl:attribute> 
        </xsl:element> 
        </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>   

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your sample and it seems to work if you make your `brand` path absolute:

```
<div class="logo">
    <xsl:variable name="brand" select="/books/book/a/ItemFields/ItemMainCategory"/>
    <xsl:if test="$isMissingImg = 'false'">
        <h2>Hello</h2> <!-- this condition is working--> 
        <xsl:if test="$brand = 'White T-shirt'"> <!-- this condition is NOT working--> 
            <xsl:element name="img"> 
                <xsl:attribute name="src">  
                    <xsl:text>https://example.com/images/black.png</xsl:text> 
                </xsl:attribute> 
                <xsl:attribute name='border'>0</xsl:attribute> 
            </xsl:element> 
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>   
  </div>
```

By the way, you could simplify this code like this:

```
<div class="logo">
    <xsl:variable name="brand" select="/books/book/a/ItemFields/ItemMainCategory"/>
    <xsl:if test="$isMissingImg = 'false'">
        <h2>Hello</h2> 
        <xsl:if test="$brand = 'White T-shirt'">
            <img src="https://example.com/images/black.png" border="0" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>   
</div>
```

You should take care of the `<xsl:if test="$isMissingImg = 'false'">`. It checks if the `$isMissingImg` does have a string value of "false" and **not** a boolean value of `false`. Keep that in mind.